# Conectar a webservice com SOAP no PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Estou tentando conectar ao webservice mas não está funcionando. O endereço wsdl é http://91.205.172.97/globalsight/services/AmbassadorWebService?wsdl

Código PHP:

```
<?php
if (!class_exists('SoapClient'))
{
    die ("You haven't installed the PHP-Soap module.");
}

$clientSoap = new SoapClient( 
                "http://91.205.172.97/globalsight/services/AmbassadorWebService?wsdl", 
                array( 
                    'username'  =>  'teste123',
                    'password'  =>  'teste123.'
                )
              );

$params = array( 'username'     =>  'teste123',
                 'password'  =>  'teste123.' );

$result = $clientSoap->login( $params );
print_r($result);    

?>
```

A resposta:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /home/brgwe507/public_html/previas/wp-content/plugins/sample-globalsight/sample-globalsight.php:31 Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://localhos...', '', 1, 0)
#1 /home/brgwe507/public_html/previas/wp-content/plugins/sample-globalsight/sample-globalsight.php(31): SoapClient->__call('login', Array)
#2 /home/brgwe507/public_html/previas/wp-content/plugins/sample-globalsight/sample-globalsight.php(31): SoapClient->login('')
#3 /home/brgwe507/public_html/previas/wp-includes/plugin.php(496): sample_globalsight('')
#4 /home/brgwe507/public_html/previas/wp-admin/admin.php(212): do_action('sample_globalsi...', Array)
#5 {main} thrown in /home/brgwe507/public_html/previas/wp-content/plugins/sample-globalsight/sample-globalsight.php on line 31
```

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos até agora. Eu me esqueci de colocar o código que está funcionando com o curl. Com este código eu consigo me conectar ao webservice, mas não consigo fazer mais nada porque quando tento fazer outra chamada com o token gerado recebo a mensagem "stream closed":

```
    function sample_globalsight(){

class soap_client{

    public $xmlRequest;
    public $header;

    function set_header(){
        $this->header = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
            "Accept: text/xml",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "SOAPAction: \"\"",
            "Content-length: ".strlen($this->xmlRequest)
        );
    }

    function send(){
        $this->set_header();
        $soapCURL = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_URL, "http://91.205.172.97/globalsight/services/AmbassadorWebService?wsdl" );
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        1000);
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $this->xmlRequest);
        curl_setopt($soapCURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $this->header);
        //Executing Curl Here.
        $result = curl_exec($soapCURL);
        if($result === false) {
          $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soapCURL);
          $result = $err;
          //echo "This is text".$err;
        }
        curl_close($soapCURL);
        return $result;
    }
}
$data ='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.globalsight.com/webservices/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:login soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <p_username xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">teste123</p_username>
         <p_password xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">teste123.</p_password>
      </web:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
$obj = new soap_client();
$obj->xmlRequest = $data;
print_r($obj->send());

}
```

Comment: O endereço realmente precisa de autenticação ?

Comment: Eu tentei com e sem autenticação e deu o mesmo erro nos dois casos.

Comment: @RicardoLimaGonçalves pelo que eu li no erro `SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://localhos...', '', 1, 0)` me parece que está tentando conectar ao *localhost*, o que é estranho. Será que está acontecendo algum redirecionamento do servidor `http://91.205.172.97`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento achei isso estranho também. Como é a primeira vez que uso esse tipo de api achei que era normal isso. No xml gerado pelo `http://91.205.172.97/globalsight/services/AmbassadorWebService?wsdl` aparece a segunite informação `<wsdl:service name="AmbassadorService">
<wsdl:port binding="impl:AmbassadorWebServiceSoapBinding" name="AmbassadorWebService">
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/globalsight/services/AmbassadorWebService"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>`.

Comment: Era disso mesmo que eu ia comentar agora. Então está linha é estranha. Acredito que na documentação deste WebService você tenha que definir o dominio e porta de redirecionamento (teoria). Ou então é um BUG (falha de configuração deles). Que serviço é este, tem documentação?

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas acho que é algum tipo de proxy e talvez tenha como desabilitar, veja: https://github.com/tingley/globalsight/blob/master/main6/envoy/src/webserviceClients/ambassador-desktop/desktopicon/src/com/globalsight/www/webservices/AmbassadorServiceLocator.java#L25

Comment: É a API do GlobalSight, um sistema de gerenciamentod e tradução open source.[http://www.globalsight.com/wiki/index.php/GlobalSight_Web_Services_API]

Comment: Vou alterar o localhost pro IP e recompilar pra ver se funciona...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21165/discussion-between-ricardo-lima-goncalves-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: Adicionei o código em curl na pergunta. Não sei se ajuda...

Comment: @RicardoLimaGonçalves Você desabilitou o [**filtro de IP**](http://www.globalsight.com/wiki/index.php/GlobalSight_Web_Services_API#IP_filter)?

Comment: @QMechanic73 desabilitei sim... pra testar se estava mesmo desabilitado, reativei e fiz a chamada do curl por um servidor que não estava na lista e foi bloqueado. Depois desativei novamente.

Answer (score 2):

Dei uma olhada no WSDL e me parece que a forma correta de utilizar esse método seria:

```
<?php
// Tente desabilitar o cache da WSDL
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

$client = new SoapClient('http://91.205.172.97/globalsight/services/AmbassadorWebService?wsdl');
try {
    $client->login('teste123', 'teste123.');
} catch (SoapFault $excp) {
    // Tratar exceção
}
```

A classe `SoapClient` expõe um método chamado `__getFunctions` que retorna um array com a assinatura dos métodos disponíveis.

Comment: Edison, editei sua pergunta para inserir o código que estava no pastebin. Dessa forma garantimos que o código vai sempre estar disponível aqui caso aconteça alguma coisa com o site externo.

Comment: @Edson, obrigado mas não deu certo. Mesmo erro: 'SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /home/brgwe507/public_html/previas/wp-content/plugins/sample-globalsight/sample-globalsight.php:22`. Consigo conectar com curl, mas preciso do token que retorna do login para chamar outras funções e quando tento fazer nava chamada com o curl usando esse token recebo a mensagem de stream closed.

Comment: @Edson, sobre o filtro tem sim e eu até desabilitei para testar. Mas se fosse esse o caso não conseguiria conectar com curl tb...

Comment: @RicardoLimaGonçalves em algum momento a URL da WSDL mudou? Tente desabilitar o cache da WSDL e executar novamente. Editei a minha resposta com esses ajustes

Comment: @EdsonJoséLimaJunior o proxy do apache estava redirecionando pro localhost, e gerava essa saída no wsdl `<wsdl:service name="AmbassadorService"> <wsdl:port binding="impl:AmbassadorWebServiceSoapBinding" name="AmbassadorWebService"> <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/globalsight/services/AmbassadorWebService"/> </wsdl:port> </wsdl:service>` mas agora está ok. A URL em si não mudou. Já tinha tentado desabilitar o cache ao carregar a classe e não tinha funcionado. Não funcionou também com init_set... Estou trabalhando no código-fonte do ws pra ver se consigo descobrir o problema.

Comment: Adicionei o código que consigo conectar com curl na pergunta... não sei se ajuda em algo...